# how to get a row index in dynamic table via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery to dynamic create table content in page, how can I get the row number index of this dynamic table? In the following code, when I click the "show more" link, I use index function in following code, but it not work. How to solve this issue? Thanks.

```
 $.getJSON(JsonURL,
        function(data){

            $.each(data, function(index, item){
                var obj = item;
                books.push(book);
            });
            for (var i = 0; i<obj.length; i++) {
                var tr=$('<tr></tr>'); 
                $('<td>'+ obj[i].name +'</td>').appendTo(tr);
                $('<td>'+ obj[i].category +'</td>').appendTo(tr);
                $('<td><a class=\'showMore\' href=#>'+ 'show more' +'</a></td>').appendTo(tr);
                tr.appendTo('#tableBody');
            };
    });
    $('a .showMore').on('click', function(event) {
        var rowindex = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent);
        console.debug('rowindex', rowindex);
    });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically created elements:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.showMore', function(event) {
    var rowindex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    console.debug('rowindex', rowindex);
});
```

Please note that you dont need a space between `a` and `.showmore` because `a .showmore` will select any elements with class `showmore` which is a child of an anchor.

Also, `.parent()` is a method so you need `()` after `parent` if you want to use `.parent()`.

Another suggestion is that instead of multiple `parent()` method, you can use **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

Answer (score 5):

You can try with:

```
$(document).on('click', '.showMore', function(event) {
    var rowindex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    console.debug('rowindex', rowindex);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on('click',".showMore", function(event) {
    var rowindex = $(this).parents("tr").index();
    console.debug('rowindex', rowindex);
});
```

Event delegation allows you to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector, whether those children exist now or are added in the future.